# Div's order and appearance on a site

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having problem with my div's order and the button's don't work propperly. All I need is to show users a **div with massive content** and right after one clicks *begin test* button situated under the long text the content disappears and the **test div** shows up.

I'm aware that this part of js ignores my **large content div** and I'm also aware that there is a simple way to sort it out. I'm a beginner so please show me how to properly cope with this kind of issues. I'll be much obliged :)

```
        init: function(){
        $('.btnNext').click(function(){
            if ($('input[type=radio]:checked:visible').length == 0) {
              //*!!!!!!*//          
                return false;
            }
            $(this).parents('.rama_nastepne_pytanie').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
            });
            var el = $('#progress');
            el.width(el.width() + 86 + 'px');
        });
        $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.rama_nastepne_pytanie').fadeOut(500, function(){
                $(this).prev().fadeIn(500)
            });
```

Here's the full code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4srj9jh/)

Comment: Please short up the fiddle. There is to much text in it. And could you please write one clear question. I've read through your whole question several times but i have no clear idea what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jquery to hide the test part when the page loads and then use jquery to hide the "massive content" and show the "test div" once the button to start the test has been clicked.

I have made a basic mock up on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/3put0pof/) to show what i mean.

All it uses is that small block of jquery to get the desired effect.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").hide();
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("#large-content").hide();
        $("#test").show();
        $("#btn").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This is just perfect. You're my new god from now on. :)